# Getting error message "expected an indented block"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep on getting the error message "expected an indented block"

```
month = int(input('Please enter a month in numeric form: '))
day = int(input('Please enter a day in numeric form: '))
year = int(input('Please enter a two-digit year in numeric form: '))
if month * day == year:
print ('The date is magic!')
else:
print ('The date is not magic.')
```

Comment: Indent the two print statements. (After the `:` character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, indentation is crucial. After each `:`, you must indent at least at the next line so the interpreter understands the line belongs to the block.

```
if month * day == year:
    print ('The date is magic!')
else:
    print ('The date is not magic.')
```

I suggest you to gather more information on [how indents work in Python](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Indent the code block inside the if statement should fix it.

```
month = int(input('Please enter a month in numeric form: '))
day = int(input('Please enter a day in numeric form: '))
year = int(input('Please enter a two-digit year in numeric form: '))
if month * day == year:
    print ('The date is magic!')
else:
    print ('The date is not magic.')
```